# Null Pointer Exception Mockito Argument(s) are different (WebTestClient Put bodyValue)

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, mockito, webtestclient

```
@Test
    void checkPutProfileNotFound() {
        ProfileDto profileDto = new ProfileDto("abcd@gmail.com", "abcd", null, null);
        when(profileService.putProfile(profileDto)).thenReturn(Mono.error(new NotFoundException()));
        webTestClient.put().uri("/profile/put")
                .bodyValue(profileDto)
                .exchange();
        verify(profileService, times(1)).putProfile(profileDto);
    }
```

Null Pointer Exception is caused and below error is also shown. This error is resolved if I replace profileDto object with any() in when() and verify(). I want to understand where exactly I am making mistake in my test case.

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
com.example.profile.service.ProfileService#0 bean.putProfile(
    ProfileDto(email=abcd@gmail.com, name=abcd, dob=null, number=null)
);
-> at com.example.profile.controller.ProfileControllerTest.checkPutProfileNotFound(ProfileControllerTest.java:115)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
com.example.profile.service.ProfileService#0 bean.putProfile(
    ProfileDto(email=abcd@gmail.com, name=abcd, dob=null, number=null)
);
```

Comment: Has your `ProfileDTO` an `equals` method? If not add it

Comment: @Jens Thankyou this solved the problem. Can you tell me where and why mockito is using equals method?

Comment: It will be used to compare the  data.

Comment: Oh ok understood. It will compare the object in when() and verify().

Comment: You can find a more detailed explanation in an answer for a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73745189/3305737

Comment: Ok @Jonasz. I am reading it.

Comment: Reference equality would be sufficient if you didn't create a new instance of `ProfileDTO` to pass to `putProfile`.

Comment: @tgdavies but I have created only one instance of ProfileDto and using the same in when(), bodyValue() and verify() so reference equality should have worked?

Comment: I expect webTestClient translates your dto to JSON and it is translated back to another dto instance by your endpoint.

Comment: Ok understood @tgdavies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments section adding the equals method solved the problem because it was needed for comparing the objects in when() and verify().