# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id"

Tags: java, json, junit, mockito, mockmvc

So I have been doing some testing for a server and I keep getting this error
"java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id"

This is the code that I have used. Not sure why it's not reading the jSon correctly, as it doesn't do this with all the other code written.

```
@Test
    public void registerSuccessful() throws Exception {
        User testUser1 = new User("test.com", "password", "John", "Doe", "JDoe");
        testUser1.setId(1);
        given(authService.register(testUser1)).willReturn(testUser1);

        String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testUser1);
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/auth/register")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody))
                .andExpect(status().is(201)).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is("test.com")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.password", is(testUser1.getPassword())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName", is(testUser1.getFirstName())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName", is(testUser1.getLastName())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username", is(testUser1.getUsername())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.imageUrl", is(testUser1.getImageUrl())));
    }
```

Here is the AuthController

```
 @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        User created = new User(
                registerRequest.getEmail(),
                registerRequest.getPassword(),
                registerRequest.getFirstName(),
                registerRequest.getLastName(),
                registerRequest.getUsername());

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(authService.register(created));
    }
```

Comment: Does `User` class extend `equals` method? Could you show the code of the tested controller method?

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble understanding how to get the body results from the ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(authService.register(created))

Comment: Does `User` class extend `equals` method?

Comment: It does not, but I finally figured it out!

The big was in the given function. I fixed it with

given(authService.register(any())).willReturn(testUser1);

Comment: `any()` matcher accepts any value as the name states. You might want to use some other method of matching - see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73745189/3305737